# Objective C - save UIImage as a BMP file

Tags: objective-c, c, bitmap, uiimage

Similar questions have been asked but they always contain the answer "use UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRepresentation" which will not work for me.  I need to save the file as a bitmap.

From my understanding, the UIImage data is already a bitmap.  In which case I shouldn't have to create a bitmap.  Or do I?  I found someone who posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12076216/1735836) but I'm unsure what exactly the answer is, as it is not clear to me.  I've even gone so far as to create a char pointer array but I still don't know how to save it as a bitmap.  Is there anybody out there who can help me understand how to save the UIImage as a bitmap?  Or tell me the steps and I'll research the steps.

Thank you.

---

EDIT:

I found [this tutorial](http://paulsolt.com/2010/09/ios-converting-uiimage-to-rgba8-bitmaps-and-back/) (with code) for converting the image to a bitmap but the bitmap returned is an unsigned char *.  Either I'm on the right path or I'm going down in the wrong direction.  So now I'm going to see if I can write out the unsigned char * to a .bmp file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save a Bitmap Image, represented by a CGContextRef, to the iPhone's hard drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488338/how-can-i-save-a-bitmap-image-represented-by-a-cgcontextref-to-the-iphones-ha)

Comment: Nope - That uses the UIImagePNGRepresentation.  I need to save it as a bitmap.

Comment: It does at first, but see how it exports it - as bmp using the CI context.

Comment: What should the data be in my bitmap context?

Comment: You may think this is a duplicate but I still do not have a clear answer.  I need some help, please?

Comment: Crap! Now I get it. You want to go from a PNG/JPG and output as a BMP. Sorry!

Comment: Have you looked at ***[CxImage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1300/CxImage)***?

Comment: Hi Patricia, Did you able to get the .bmp file? I am also looking for the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the category that I have pieced together for UIImage that lets me access the raw BGRA data as well as data ready to be written to disk with an appropriate bitmap header.

```
@interface UIImage (BitmapData)
- (NSData *)bitmapData;
- (NSData *)bitmapFileHeaderData;
- (NSData *)bitmapDataWithFileHeader;
@end



# pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct s_bitmap_header
{
    // Bitmap file header
    UInt16 fileType;
    UInt32 fileSize;
    UInt16 reserved1;
    UInt16 reserved2;
    UInt32 bitmapOffset;

    // DIB Header
    UInt32 headerSize;
    UInt32 width;
    UInt32 height;
    UInt16 colorPlanes;
    UInt16 bitsPerPixel;
    UInt32 compression;
    UInt32 bitmapSize;
    UInt32 horizontalResolution;
    UInt32 verticalResolution;
    UInt32 colorsUsed;
    UInt32 colorsImportant;
} t_bitmap_header;
#pragma pack(pop)

@implementation UIImage (BitmapData)

- (NSData *)bitmapData
{
    NSData          *bitmapData = nil;
    CGImageRef      image = self.CGImage;
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    UInt8           *rawData;

    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    size_t bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel;
    size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace)
    {
        // Allocate memory for raw image data
        rawData = (UInt8 *)calloc(bufferLength, sizeof(UInt8));

        if (rawData)
        {
            CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst;
            context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                            width,
                                            height,
                                            bitsPerComponent,
                                            bytesPerRow,
                                            colorSpace,
                                            bitmapInfo);

            if (context)
            {
                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

                CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height);
                CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
                CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image);

                bitmapData = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawData length:bufferLength];

                CGContextRelease(context);
            }

            free(rawData);
        }

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    }

    return bitmapData;
}

- (NSData *)bitmapFileHeaderData
{
    CGImageRef image = self.CGImage;
    UInt32     width = (UInt32)CGImageGetWidth(image);
    UInt32     height = (UInt32)CGImageGetHeight(image);

    t_bitmap_header header;

    header.fileType = 0x4D42;
    header.fileSize = (height * width * 4) + 54;
    header.reserved1 = 0x0000;
    header.reserved2 = 0x0000;
    header.bitmapOffset = 0x00000036;
    header.headerSize = 0x00000028;
    header.width = width;
    header.height = height;
    header.colorPlanes = 0x0001;
    header.bitsPerPixel = 0x0020;
    header.compression = 0x00000000;
    header.bitmapSize = height * width * 4;
    header.horizontalResolution = 0x00000B13;
    header.verticalResolution = 0x00000B13;
    header.colorsUsed = 0x00000000;
    header.colorsImportant = 0x00000000;

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:&header length:sizeof(t_bitmap_header)];
}

- (NSData *)bitmapDataWithFileHeader
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[self bitmapFileHeaderData]];
    [data appendData:[self bitmapData]];

    return [NSData dataWithData:data];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi!  I tried to use your code (with a few modifications) to generate an 8-bit grayscale bitmap, but I was unable to make the appropriate changes to get it to work.  Do you think you could help me out?  Thanks!  The question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402929/save-uiimage-as-8-bit-grayscale-bitmap