# How to create Thumbnail images for formats other than JPEG or PNG in iOS

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, uiimage

We need to create Thumbnail images for various image formats - > i.e.JPEG/PNG/16 colour, 256 colour and 24 bit Bitmap and store them to the local disk. These images will be used later for preview. The link provided supports for BMP, 
[Objective C - save UIImage as a BMP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126772/objective-c-save-uiimage-as-a-bmp-file)
can you pl. clarify if that approach can be followed for GIF/TIFF formats also.

Currently the below mentioned approach is followed for creating thumbnail images.

Step 1 : Resize images to thumbnail size

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resize, NO, 0.0);
 [oldImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, resize.width, resize.height)];
 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Step2: Save thumbnail image to local disk

```
 NSData *fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
 NSString* temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",temp,name];
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:temp 
  contents:fileData attributes:nil];
```

For PNG and JPEG formats, the methods available are

```
  i) UIImagePNGRepresentation();
 ii) UIJPEGRepresentation()
```

Pl. let me know how other image formats need to be handled, since API supports  only JPEG and PNG format. Apart from the above approach, if there are different ways to create thumbnail images pl. let me know. Any input/suggestion will be of help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - save UIImage as a BMP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126772/objective-c-save-uiimage-as-a-bmp-file)

Comment: You will have to either find a library that supports the other formats you want or write your own code to save the `UIImage` in whatever other formats you want.

Comment: Avt, The link mentioned, it provides option for us to save the BMP images. However in our case we have to support for other images formats like GIF , TIFF etc. i.e. after resizing these images we have to store them in the disk and show it as a preview to the user.